# CSS: How to avoid height expansion of flex-row by child margin?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

```
<div class="flex flex-row bg-blue-100 box-border">
  <p class="bg-red-100 m-5">
    test1
  </p>
  <p class="bg-red-100 m-5">
    test2
  </p>
</div>
```

Result:
[image]

What I Need: [image]

Comment: Change the `m-5` to `mx-5` to apply the margin to the x-axis only.

Comment: @justanotherpeter Cannot do that. This is a portion of whole page, and I need margin in y direction, but I also need div height fit the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider doing what @justanotherpeter suggested in the comments, but also adding the vertical margin on the parent to maintain the spacing required:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<div class="flex flex-row bg-blue-100 box-border my-5">
  <p class="bg-red-100 mx-5">
    test1
  </p>
  <p class="bg-red-100 mx-5">
    test2
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice! What if I don't know margins of children? My actual React code is like `<FlexRow>{children}</FlexRow>`, and I need the `FlexRow` height fit children content.

Comment: You can still remove the margins of the immediate children via the `*:!my-0` class.